# Android lean back mode

Tags: android, android-layout

In the [android doc](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/fullscreen.html), I came across the lean back mode.

> Lean Back:  Touch the screen anywhere to bring back system bars.

How do I enable this for an activity in my app? In this activity, I am trying to show a slideshow of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) is what you are looking for. If you are thinking about developing for Android TV you could look into [this](http://androidtv-codelabs.appspot.com/static/codelabs/1-androidtv-adding-leanback/#1)

Comment: Your answer led me to this page -https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim.html which is kind of what I am looking for